# Immersion of a part of the hyperbolic plane in $\mathbb{R}^3$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, isometric-immersion

I know that the [pseudosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pseudosphere) is a regular surface with Gaussian curvature $-1$ that is not complete, also this surface is not complete. Hilbert's theorem ensures that there is no isometric immersion of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb{H}^2$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$, but if we remove a point from the hyperbolic plane, can it be immersed isometrically in $\mathbb{R}^3$? What could it be?

I read this: Dini's surface provides a analytic isometric embedding of the hyperbolic plane. That region includes hyperbolic disks of any finite radius, though big disks will be wrapped many times, very tightly around the screw axis of Dini's surface. But how could I prove it? I have already tried a few days without success.

Comment: The [Dini surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dini%27s_surface), I guess

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Largest hyperbolic disk embeddable in Euclidean 3-space?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/533/largest-hyperbolic-disk-embeddable-in-euclidean-3-space)

Comment: Thanks for the comments and I have indeed read this: Dini's surface provides a analytic isometric embedding of the hyperbolic plane. That region includes hyperbolic disks of any finite radius, though big disks will be wrapped many times, very tightly around the screw axis of Dini's surface. But how could I prove it? I have already tried a few days without success.

Comment: Did you try to modify Hilbert's or Efimov's proof?

Comment: Concerning the geometry of Dini's surface and the portion of the hyperbolic plane that it represents, you might find useful the discussion at the MO question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/149842/geodesics-on-the-twisted-pseudosphere-dinis-surface.

Comment: Also, you have to be careful, because there is more than one Dini surface with Gauss curvature -1.  In fact, if you look at the formulae, you'll see the two positive parameters $(a,b) = (\cos\tau,\sin\tau)$ (with $0<\tau<\pi/2$), and for the surface with those given parameters, there is a maximal radius $r(\tau)$ for a hyperbolic disc in that surface.  In fact, $r(\tau) = \tfrac12\log\bigl((1+b)/(2-2a)\bigr)$.  Thus, to get a hyperbolic disk of a given radius embedded in a Dini surface, you have to choose $\tau$ sufficiently small.

Comment: Thank you so much @RobertBryant I will try to do the operations of what you mention. But in case you can provide a detailed answer I would greatly appreciate it since I have been trying this topic for weeks without encouraging results. An additional query. Where does my next thought fail? : "Taking the Poincaré disk and stretching the center upwards infinitely I could get the pseudosphere, then maybe and just maybe be able to get an isometric immersion of the disk minus one point" I tried at the beginning without any success.