# Modifying monkey saddles

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations

We get negative Gauss curvature K surfaces of quasi polar symmetry surface form generated from:

$$ Re  (x+ i y)^n =  a^n $$  (n  integer) with n humps above plane $ z =0$.

($ n =2,3,4 $  hyperbolic paraboloids, monkey saddles, four humped frill/ pleated shells respectively).

"Quasi" due to $n>2$ introducing circumferential pleats or frills.

What polynomial or differential relation function  yields constant negative surfaces of  $K = -1/a^2 $?

How to set up its differential equation?

Instead of $ z^n $ if a simpler $ \cos z $ is taken, no clue or handle how to modify the function in order to get a constant negative$ K. ( \cos x \cosh y = $ const)

[image: Z= cos_x cosh_y]

Comment: Embeddings of portions of the hyperbolic plane into Euclidean 3-space has been classically studied. http://mathoverflow.net/questions/533/largest-hyperbolic-disk-embeddable-in-euclidean-3-space gives some references.

Comment: There is no unique mapping it appears. About the Coral ruffles (in comments  of Oct 15 above) ,I sent a message  to Prof. Daina Taimina sometime back, says there is no known parameterization.